# inserir Style no PDF

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte conteudo **HTML** sendo gerado em um loop **PHP**

```
$html .= "  
<ul class='border'>
   <li style='text-align: left; border-bottom: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;'><label class='labelPequeno'>Gcéu</label> : " . $celula[ "nomeCelula" ] . "</li>
   <li style='text-align: left; border-bottom: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;' class='backCinza'><label class='labelPequeno'>Supervisor de Setor</label> : " . $nomeLideres[ "nomeLiderSetor" ] . "</li>
   <li style='text-align: left; border-bottom: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;'><label class='labelPequeno'>Líder</label> : " . $celula[ "nomeLider" ] . "</li>
   <li style='text-align: left;'><label class='labelPequeno'>Auxiliar</label> : " . $celula[ "nomeAuxiliar" ] . "</li>
</ul>
<ul class='border'>
   <li style='text-align: left; border-bottom: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;'><label class='labelPequeno'>Dias que acontece</label> : " . $celula[ "diaReunioes" ] . "</li>
   <li style='text-align: left;'><label class='labelPequeno'>Membros Ativos</label> : " . $membros . "</li>
</ul>";
```

Isso acontece na *pagina* **x.php** por exemplo.

Nessa mesma pagina **x.php** existe um **form** que *envia*, via **POST**, um campo **hidden** com o **value** sendo a **variavel** acima criada com seu **conteudo** para uma **pagina** que vai *gerar* um arquivo **pdf**.

Estou gerando **PDF's** com o codigo abaixo usando a biblioteca **FPDF**

```
require_once "_classes/_util/_PDF/PDF.php";

$html = $_POST["htmlPDF"];

$pdf = new PDF;
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->WriteHTML( utf8_decode ( $html ) );
$pdf->Output("relatorio.pdf","D");
```

Acontece que nesse arquivo eu não posso inserir as chamadas aos arquivos de style.

O **problema**:

```
$_POST["htmlPDF"]
```

Tráz um **HTML** .

Nesse caso, o **pdf** está saindo sem **style**.

Será que existe uma forma de quando estiver sendo gerada a **variável** que contem o **html**, aproveitar e **inserir** via **código** (**dinamicamente**) os **estilos** *direto* nas **tags**?

Answer (score 0):

A não ser que essa `API` de `PDF` remova a tag `<link>` vc pode usar tranquilamente um `style.css` dentro do `body`

Veja aqui que a tag `link` é um *flow content* e é permitida dentro do `body` https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content

> Se um elemento de `link` tiver um atributo `rel` que contém apenas palavras-chave que são `body-ok`, então o elemento é dito como sendo permitido no corpo. Isso significa que o elemento pode ser usado onde o conteúdo da frase é esperado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sup>*Fonte:* https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#body-ok</sup>

Veja que mesmo testando no validador oficial da W3C não é apresentado nenhum problema. https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código usado no teste:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    
    <h1><i class="fa fa-car"></i>Lorem, ipsum.</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bom, vamos la. Tenho um foreach que gera uma estrutura html. Ok? Tenho um form com um input hidden com o conteúdo HTML sem os devidos styles incorporados às tag's. Ok? Esse form, leva o valu do Input hidden para uma página que tem o código que está na pergunta. Adiconei os arquivos de css antes do bloco php e deu ruim. Então queria saber se existe algum reurso tipo $pdf->SetCss e enviar o linl do aquivo..

Comment: @CarlosRocha não vou saber te dizer, o que posso afirmar, é que mesmo não sendo uma prática muito indicada vc pode incluir a tag link com seu arquivo .css direto dentro da tag body, não precisa ser exclusivamente dentro da tag head. (apesar de que dentro da tag head é o aconselhável)

Comment: no arquivo que contem a chamada para a biblioteca pode aenas a saida HTML.
Nãopode colocar o estilo

Comment: @CarlosRocha vc não vai colocar `style` vc vai colocar `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../seu.css" />` em algum lugar ai.... Não sei se vai dar certo, é só uma dica, e é permitido pela W3C, já pela API que vc está usando não sei se funciona...